# Creating map of point and classifing new points

Tags: algorithm, 3d, maps, classification

I've created map of points in 3D space. They are grouped in areas (clouds), which tells us about places of some activity, i.e: a cloud of points where the user is sitting.

Now I have new point `P` and I would like to know if it is inside/near the known cloud on the map or not.

Currently my algorithm is calculating distance between each point in cloud with point `P` and check the value with a threshold. If any point in cloud distance is lower than the threshold, the return value is positive. But this method could be insufficient for some cases.

How can this be implemented more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) algorithm (such as [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), for example) to cluster the "clouds".

You can find the "center" of each cluster (offline), and check of the new point `p` is close enough to any of these centers (online).